# Finding a path between two stations from three routes

Tags: java, data-structures, dijkstra, path-finding

Using a map I need to find the path between two stations.

Per example, if the user says he/she is in **Lawrence**, and  wants to go to **Eglinton**, the output should be `"Lawrence, 100, 30, Kennedy, 19, Eglinton"`.

There is no problem using available code like the Dijkstra's algorithm or the A* search algorithm (which is probably the best one for what I need, not sure). But I do need  to use some type of array, queue or list. Would this implementation of the map work? Or do I have to create a matrix?

```
String ThreeArray[][] = new String [2][7];
ThreeArray[0][0] = "140";
ThreeArray[0][1] = "134";
ThreeArray[0][2] = "Lawrence";
ThreeArray[0][3] = "100";
ThreeArray[0][4] = "30";
ThreeArray[0][5] = "Summerhill";
ThreeArray[0][6] = "Warden";
ThreeArray[0][7] = "Broadview";
ThreeArray[1][0] = "Chester";
ThreeArray[1][1] = "Kennedy";
ThreeArray[1][2] = "19";
ThreeArray[1][3] = "Eglinton";
ThreeArray[2][0] = "Donalds";
ThreeArray[2][1] = "Davisville";
ThreeArray[2][2] = "Yorkdale";
ThreeArray[2][3] = "Midland";
```

Answer (score 0):

This might come in handy: https://www.baeldung.com/java-graphs. You could represent your data into a graph and then apply which ever formula you find fit to calculate distances.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try creating adjacency list in Java to deal with graph problems.